# Flask and ajax: update one dropdown menu when the other one is selected

Tags: ajax, flask

I have two dropdown menus in a flask window. The following two for loops create the two drodown menus (the outer one will have two elements are there are two dropdown menus)

```
 {% for key, values in fields.items() %}
 {{key}} <BR>
        <select name="{{key}}">
            {%for value in values%}
             <option value="{{value}}">{{value}}</option>
            {%endfor %}
         </select>
 <BR><BR>
 {%endfor %}
```

What is the best way to update the second dropdown depending on the selection of the first one, without having to reload the whole page. Is there any flask plugins I could use or will I have to dig deep into ajax?

Comment: Flask is server side only. You need JS code for this. Flask can generate JS code defining the structure of the hierarchy (as JSON object for example), but it will be JS code running in the browser using it to update fields dynamically. AJAX is unnecessary for all this unless all your data calls are asynchronous or you don't want to pass too much data at once.

Comment: To me this seems a very basic functionality. Any GUI has a way to call a function 'onclick' or 'onchange'. Is there no equivalent provided by some framework for a web interface?

Comment: Once the template is rendered, the server has no more control over it. You'll have to use some client-side mechanism to update the 2nd drop-down.

Comment: Any suggestions what framework would be good for that? I don't need anything complicated just a simple onChange-->submit

Comment: @nickpick I'm confused. Are you looking for code that runs in the browser (GUI) or code that runs in Python on the server (Flask)?

Comment: I think it will need to be in the browser, i.e. javascript